# How to search for keywords and count the size fragment in unix/linux command? (restrict enzyme digestion)

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics

For example, I have a `.fa` fasta file like this, performing restrict enzyme digestion of `HindIII`

```
ataaaatactggcaaacagaatccagcagcacatcaaaaagcttatccac
AGTAATTCATTATATCAAAATGCTCCAggccaggcgtggtggcttatgcc
tgtaatcccagcactttgggaggtcgaagtgggcggatcacttgaggtca
aatgtagtaagattatctcagattttaaccgctgtattaaaaaagcttaa
tataatccatgaaaattggaggccaaactaagcttagatacaaacatcta
ggagttggagactagcctggccaacatgatgaaaccccgtctctaataat
aggaaaaggagaggaatgaggttggaaaatagtacacaggaagcttcaac
```

I am finding sequence `aagctt` including both capital and small letter, and then separate the string to be `a` and `agctt`

treat each fragment as separate units, and count their length

```
fragment 1 from 1 to 39: length 39
ataaaatactggcaaacagaatccagcagcacatcaaaa

fragment 2 from 40 to 193: length 154
                                       agcttatccac
AGTAATTCATTATATCAAAATGCTCCAggccaggcgtggtggcttatgcc
tgtaatcccagcactttgggaggtcgaagtgggcggatcacttgaggtca
aatgtagtaagattatctcagattttaaccgctgtattaaaaa

fragment 3 from 194 to 230: length 37
                                           agcttaa
tataatccatgaaaattggaggccaaacta

fragment 4 from 231 to 341: length 111
                              agcttagatacaaacatcta
ggagttggagactagcctggccaacatgatgaaaccccgtctctaataat
aggaaaaggagaggaatgaggttggaaaatagtacacagga

fragment 5 from 342 to 350: length 9
                                         agcttcaac
```

I don't necessarily need the unix/linux command, just need the pseudocode for this question

I had tried to use `sed -i 's/AAGCTT/A\'$'\nAGCTT/g'` to separate the `a` with `agctt`, and `wc -l` to calculate the length, but I cannot get the length of the whole fragment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Can you clarify the 'segment' ? Is it a sequence that starts with 'agctt' and ends with with an 'a' followed by another 'agctt' ? Can the 'agctt' pattern be broken over line boundaries ?

Comment: I hope the `aagctt` to be separated as `a` & `agctt`, the pattern should only contain in the same line

Comment: Install Emboss package, which has many useful bioinformatics utilities. Use `conda install emboss`, or `conda create --name emboss emboss`, for example. The `restrict` command can give the output you are looking for: http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/cvs/emboss/apps/restrict.html . I would avoid reinventing the wheel and rolling out your own code for this common task.

Comment: Consider also migrating to Bionformatics.SE, where this question would likely get more answers, and also less likely to get closed.

Comment: See also: What's the best way to find all the possible cutting sites of an sequence-specific enzyme?:
https://www.biostars.org/p/149110/ , In Silico Genome Digestion ?: https://www.biostars.org/p/948/

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo-code that will work, assuming the whole file can fit into memory. It has 2 steps:

- Combine all the lines into one big string
- Repeatedly search for the pattern, and return the fragments offset
- Assumes index(s, pattern, pos) search for 'pattern' in 's', starting as position pos (Perl style).

```
  # Read complete input into memory
S = ""
while read P ; do
   S = S + P

  # Search for occurences
PREV=0
N=0
while true
    NEXT=index(S, 'aagcct', PREV+1)
    if ( NEXT < 0 ) break   # no more occurences
    N=N+1
    print "Fragement ", N, " from ", PREV, " to ", NEXT, ": length", NEXT-PREV+1
    print substr(S, PREV, NEXT-PREV) 
    PREV=NEXT
```

The original question indicate that the pattern need to be split for the purpose of calculating the printed offset. This part is a little unclear, and is not accounted for in this solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the pattern `aagctt` spanning across lines should not be counted, the pattern should be splited at the position between `a` and `agctt`